# Gnuplot no longer has widgets or icons

Tags: linux, x11, gnuplot

On my old machine, when I ran gnuplot, it looked something like this:

[image]
(this screenshot isn't from my old machine -- I spun up a VM to take the above)

On my new machine, it looks like this:

[image]

Notice there are no icons at all, and (not shown), I can't select a portion of the graph to automatically zoom in like I could previously.

I concede I'm using different versions of gnuplot and even different operating systems, but there seems to be something more fundamentally wrong here.

Any obvious guesses as to what's wrong before I start examining the problem in more detail? Any debugging tips?

On my new machine, I did try "set term wxt" inside gnuplot only to get "unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list", which seemed a bit strange.

Comment: *"I concede I'm using different versions of gnuplot and even different operating systems"* It might be helpful to include details of what these are - it's possible one of them has dropped `wxWidgets` in favor of `qt`

Comment: @steeldriver This solved my problem, sort of. On CentOS 7.2, my new system, the yum-installed gnuplot errors on both `set terminal wxt` AND `set terminal qt`. So, I removed the yum-installed version, built from source, and now all is well, except that removing gnuplot also removed maxima, and reinstalling maxima will automatically reinstall gnuplot. Of course, I can install maxima from source, but it's vaguely annoying (I blame the package managers!)